# Creating depth chart using highcharts and creating bids and asks in such a way that bids and asks are created from center of chart

Tags: angular, reactjs, highcharts

I am having bids and asks data to create a depth chart.

So in the following image, I am having a number of bids and a number of asks in the same length. So the center's current price line remains in the center.

But when the length of bids or asks increases than another one, the center current price line moves to either side of the graph. I need to place this line in the center always.

[image]

Like in image 2, when the number of asks in only 1, the current price centerline moves to the right side of the graph. How could I always make it stay in the center?
Also remember, I need asks on the left side of the centerline and bids on the right side of the centerline. these both should origin from the centerline

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by adding the plotLine dynamically based on a computed value in the `chart.events.render` callback function. Check demo and code posted below:

```
chart: {
  type: 'area',
  zoomType: 'xy',
  events: {
    load: function() {
      const chart = this;

      setTimeout(function() {
        chart.series[0].addPoint([
          0.1513,
          34.1319
        ]);
      }, 2000);
    },
    render: function() {
      const chart = this;
      const xAxis = chart.xAxis[0];

      let xData1 = chart.series[0].xData,
        xData2 = chart.series[1].xData,
        value = (xData1[0] + xData2[xData2.length - 1]) / 2;

      if (chart.customPriceValue !== value) {
        chart.customPriceValue = value;

        xAxis.update({
          plotLines: [{
            color: '#888',
            value: value,
            width: 1,
            label: {
              text: 'Actual price',
              rotation: 90
            }
          }]
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zrd3meyq/1/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#update

Comment: thanks for Answer, but the centerline I need to create dynamically with the value from the database and i need to put that value in the center.  I don't need to make center value by dividing axis into half.

Comment: I showed you an example of how to do it dynamically, you can compute values from a database it's not a problem.

Comment: its a problem, as in your fiddle example. Actual price line lies between 0.14 and 0.15. but this should lie between asks and bid at 0.1523. and this point should become center of axis.

Comment: Ok, I've prepared an appropriate example and edited my answer. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zrd3meyq/1/